# Unit Test case to cover router.navigate.then in jasmine angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

mockRouter does not cover inside then,

`let mockRouter = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate') };`

Need a solution for coverage of below code

`this.router.navigate(['path/to']) .then(() => { window.location.reload(); });`

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No, but I have used spy event to return value, which worked but that is not solution to verify